# Google App Script getRange() method cannot be invoked with null

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function doGet(){

  try{

    var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate().setTitle('Web App').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
    var x = t;

  } catch(error){

    var errorSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('...MySpreadSheetID...').getSheetByName('errors');
    var cell = errorSheet.getRange('A1').offset(errorSheet.getLastRow(), 0);
    cell.setValue(new Date() + ' function doGet():  ' + error)

  }

  return html;

}
```

Why does the getRange() Method does not work.

It states that getRange() of null cannot be invoked?

Answer (score 1):

The [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column) expects at least one argument (depending on the arguments configuration). Probably, there is no tab named `errors` in your spreadsheet.

**Suggestion:**

If you want to add a new row at the next available row, you can use the [appendRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)) method, just consider this method expects an array of values. Your catch statement should look like this:

```
  } catch(error){

    var errorSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('...MySpreadSheetID...').getSheetByName('errors');
    errorSheet.appendRow([new Date() + ' function doGet():  ' + error])
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SpreadsheetApp.openById(...) refers to "...MySpreadSheetID...", which probably is not defined.

You need to provide a proper ID of a defined spreadsheet in your account.

/edit: Its either the Spreadsheet not defined or the sheet within your spreadsheet, which is not defined.

Comment: I think the user didn't want to share the `id` of the document he is working on, since it's not relevant. If I'm not mistaken the error message that its displayed when the id is wrong is `Illegal spreadsheet key`

Comment: @ocordova the usere also didn't share the error message, so you are only asuming the result? So its either spreadsheet or sheet not defined... I edited this post.

Comment: If you don't pass a valid `id` to the [openById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) method it throws the `Illegal spreadsheet key` error on that line. The [getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename) method returns `null` if there is no sheet with the given name, so `errorSheet` is `null` and then calling getRange of `errorSheet` will throw the error `Cannot call method "getRange" of null` that matches the title of the question, I also think it's there is no tab named `errors`.